# Too strict moderation by goldPseudo Moderator

Tags: support, moderators, moderation

Today and since I have joined islam.se, I have seen that almost all of the decisions made by the moderators against other member and me, are too much strict.
Today, during a chat thread, I was blocked for multiple times for just sharing my opinion about the Shias, "which is even accepted by the Shias themselves" there is nothing dos-respectful or non-civil in it, but he kept on blocking me for this. Also, he has blocked a user Ali, for just sharing a video "videos are also just opinions about anyone else". The videos of all kinds are viable everywhere, anyone has right to see, agree or dis-agree with them, it’s not like it was porn or something that the user was blocked.

I personally think goldPseudo needs to be removed from islam.se moderator-ship. As there are many other Meta complaints about him by many other members. i am going to present anger of other members as well, so that this case can be seriously considered and a decision can be made against him. Because his moderator-ship is destroying the actual purpose of site.

**I am not sure but even the comments direct to him, he deletes them right away. i wrote a comment against his reply, and he deleted it, without any notification.**

Comment: Lot of down votes, and not even a single comment for the reason.

Comment: Downvotes in meta mean disagreement. I disagree with your post because if it weren't for his strictness. Guys at StackOverflow would have closed this place long time ago. There are so many things while accepted culturally or in some muslim communities, are wrong and should not be mentioned in a site run by a secular company.

Comment: Thats the point, the moderators should be actually Practical followrrs of islam, not seculars. Islam and secularism, is like east and west. thats the reason so many members are not happy , specifically his moderation. as his views are based on secular values and not practical islam. and if something is right, it stands on its own.100 wise people are better than 10000 fools.

Comment: Also, Meta, as all SC sites is a question answer site. and proper reason for downvote needs to be mentioned

Comment: @Farhan, I agree with you, I dont know why.., I assume we must create a free environment for users to participate in discussion, not to escape.. !  if for example i am a moderator, it doesnt mean that i should try to delete many questions..., oh, I hope he take care more than before.

Comment: @Farhan,Although I think our sects are not the same, but I feel our goal is the same(to find the reality). and thank you for your courage that mentioed the matter, Since I reckon many users afraid to show their complaints because of .., but you frankly mentioned the issue.

Comment: of course tis solely my opinion that many users are afraid that their complaints make them..  God knows, perhaps I am wrong!

Comment: @Farhan This is a site about Islam, not an Islamic site. I think you are confusing those. There is a certain way things work here. If you don't like some aspect, you can try convincing others to follow your way or accept how things work. Otherwise, move on to another website. Internet is big.

Comment: [If a person is feeling jealous, what should they do?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23441/if-a-person-is-feeling-jealous-what-should-they-do)

Comment: Well we are all human and typo's happen but note that in general if you are addressing somebody it would be nice and polite to address him correctly (with the username in this case). I'd take care of that even if I was complaining somebody! (I edited your Question and the answer of @muslim1 because of that)

Comment: @Farhan "Thats the point, the moderators should be actually Practical followrrs of islam, not seculars. Islam and secularism, is like east and west." I don't know how you can categorize GoldPseudo and other moderators as seculars. But the thing is, that this site is in fact a StackExchange site, and do you know what StackExchange sites are, or what they are supposed to be?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had the experience of goldpseudo deleting an answer in which I presented some relevant scholarly references which (I assume) he considered irrelevant or did not like - perhaps because they were more modernist and liberal in tone.
So I posted another answer challenging his deletion - which has not been deleted yet!

Postcript - my challenge has been deleted by goldpseudo. I guess he does not consider the opinion of al-Ghazali, one of the most prominent and influential jurists and mystics of Sunni Islam, d. 505 AH, to be relevant to the issue of the permissibility of music in Islam.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. It's deleted now.

Comment: As we see here in his reply, Goldpseudo oversteps his duty by deleting answers he does not personally agree with. But he probably does a good job in weeding out the off-the-wall comments and rants you get in reddit and youtube.

Answer (score 12):

You are not being honest.

You were blocked from chat for bringing up charged political discussions, in particular referring to critics of ISIS as "brainwashed", "blind" and "deaf". This is not likely to be a particularly constructive discussion anywhere, but it is particularly off-topic and ill-advised in a chat room dedicated to the discussion of the Islamic faith.

You were warned *multiple* times about this, and you ignored the warnings. So you got a short time-out.

I could address the rest of your complaints, but frankly I'm not motivated to do so as they're built on this foundation of dishonesty. If you wish for a constructive discussion about moderator actions, it behooves you to be candid about the scenarios in which those actions occurred.

#### See also:

- [Political and Controversial Discussions in the Chat Rooms](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/political-and-controversial-discussions-in-the-chat-rooms)
- [How to deal with a rude and aggressive moderator?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/how-to-deal-with-a-rude-and-aggressive-moderator/1105#1105)
- [Take pride in your community, and work to build a site you can be proud of](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/take-pride-in-your-community-and-work-to-build-a-site-you-can-be-proud-of)

Comment: are you referring to me?

Comment: I'm addressing the author of the question I'm answering.

Comment: and who is author of question?

Comment: Don't waste my time.

Comment: @Farhan Yes, he's referring to you.

Answer (score 10):

Well I, for one, disagree with the suggestion that goldPseudo be removed from moderatorship.  I feel that he's been doing an outstanding job, and whatever strictness he has shown so far has only been what is necessary to allow all Muslims to feel welcome on the site while simultaneously dealing with the powder keg that is having all Muslims welcome on the same site.  Rumour has it, many Muslim groups don't really get along with each other so well when left to their own devices.

Also, I may be biased.

Comment: I agree with what you say. However, I also think you over use the mod powers, e.g. deleting posts without enough explanation is not good moderation. Just to give an example, I have no idea why you have deleted [this question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14741/). Documenting your actions so others can understand why you take particular actions is important part of moderation. It should be clear why you did so for anyone who visits the post. I know it can be a lot of work, but that is part of the job.

Comment: See item 3 of what to expect as a community moderator [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Comment: Obviously you would say this

Comment: Mr Goldee a small [reminder](http://quran.com/4/36).... Plz don't mind...

Comment: @AbuAbdulQayyum It's called "defending myself against unjust accusations" combined with "having a sense of humour", both of which traits I highly encourage in others, Muslim or not.

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing wrong with discussing the views of any sect so long as you don't pass negative *immature* judgements on them.

Keep in mind, any fair critique of any particular sect (or any group of people) is better to take place in presence of their representatives so that they have the opportunity to present their views and defenses, and make sure you even understand their beliefs and practices correctly before going on attacking them!

Therefore, public judgements, denunciations and condemnations against large groups of people when done in absence of their representatives can be open to charges of defamation, backbiting and hate-mongering. I think this is an ill practice that goldPseudo is trying to prevent from becoming a norm in this site. But admittedly this took me, too, a little time to understand this wise rationale behind his perceived 'strict' moderation.

Comment: Are you aware of that the Meta is full of complaints against goldpseudo? have you searched meta before posting this answer? if not, i believe you should.

Comment: @Farhan, Yes, I have done that before! But the mere existence of protests doesn't make it right! I personally may have *certain* objections to some moderators decisions (as I had) but that doesn't mean all protests against moderation are reasonable or that I agree with all of them!

Comment: Thanks, but please also look at the answer of muslim1. as his views are exatyl,what i faced against him

Answer (score 5):

I would write my 2 cents here about goldpseudo since I had some interaction with him in the past.

Positives

- The **most active member** on the site
- **Available** on the chat most of the time
- The above two points show he is very dedicated to the site.

Negatives

- **Has ego problem**. You cannot question his decision even in chat, or you will blocked for *disrespecting* him. Once he deletes an answer he never undeletes it even when fixed. He perhaps thinks of it as his insult.
- **Biased against shia**. He has deleted tons of posts from shia users for so called plagiarism or low quality. His main fault lies in the fact that he did not scrutinizes sunni post on the same level!
- **takes personnel feuds against users** Deleted highly up voted answers from this shia user. Even when the OP fixed all the problem with the post and posted another answer, goldpseudo was adamant to delete that answer too citing that it is not useful (it did get +2 votes).
- **Impolite**. I have seen him being rude, bullying and impolite in chat with me and other users. He used the word "Shut up" for me in the chat, but he is still the moderator. Was constantly bullying other users (for threats that they will be blocked).
- **Is not very active on meta**. Now this would solve a lot of problems if he was. As I said he is most active moderator who deletes tons of posts etc, it would really be helpful if he was active on meta as well but he is not (lately he has been). I personally think that would greatly help with users frustrations if he was active on meta since he is the most active moderator.
- **Not welcoming to new users**. I have seen him deleting post of new users (shia user mainly) without welcoming them and deleting their answers *repeatedly*. One should know that new users need some time to get familiar with the site but not according to this moderator.

I do not think that he is a good fit for moderator because of his temper and bias against shia. I am worried that shia user are not welcomed here at all mainly because of him.

Neutral Points

All blames do not fall with goldpseudo. **The problem is other moderators also**. If we thing goldpseudo is really doing an awesome moderation, then by that definition, the rest of the moderators are doing extremely poor job because they are hardly involved in any controversial decisions. That means they are doing nothing at all.

**The other moderators are silent** and have given free hand to this one moderator. This in my view is not helpful at all. Having so much voice against a moderator is not good. Other moderators need to step in but they don't.

So unchecked from other moderators and with support from SE team, he is all set to ruin the site. Note that I do not have any personnel conflict with any moderator. I am passionate about this site like any other user.

**I hope that I have not offended this moderator. I am only expressing this because I think these can be improved.**

Comment: I agree with some of your points and disagree with some others. But just for one thing, how do you explain the fact that this time he is accused of bias *towards* Shiites? I think he as the most dedicated mod has become the sole target of all the blames simply because he is the most dedicated mod. What frustrates me is poor community moderation by other users.

Comment: @infatuated I actually have not seen the chat session that OP is talking about so I have not commented on that part. It is my general observation. Being *committed* to get rid of shia users is *not* good moderation. Hope I am not offending anyone.

Comment: I think you're misjudging him. From my experience he doesn't seem biased towards or against any sect.

Comment: I think all the dissatisfaction only stems from the fact he is just being 'strict' about moderation, and nothing else!

Comment: I can't really talk about one moderator since I don't know who takes actions but try flaging a sunni post and see what happens. They try flaging a shia post and see what happens. Sunni posts are not deleted and are let to sit with extremely low quality. Not the same case with Shia posts. I hope he is not biased but I think we all acknowledged, every one is opinionated.

Comment: "I can't really talk about one moderator since I don't know who takes actions." That's the point!

Comment: Well I do see names of the moderators who took the action on a post but when I flag a particular post e.g, then I don't have  a clue which moderator addressed it. That was my point.

Comment: @Farhan same thing happened to me. The problem here is no other person jumps in to settle the matter. We have this problem, other moderators stay quite in such matter and generally they do not go against a mod even if he is at fault. Well at least he replied to your post so that's good.

Comment: @muslim1, Farhan is sunni. so...... we can conclude he is not biased against shia only ?!

Comment: @Sohaeb this is not where him being Sunni is the problem. If you look at the chat, you see someone is really bossy and policing everyone around him. People will obviously get offended by this. You can say the same thing in a polite manner. `enough is enough` out of blue does not sound right to me.

Comment: goldpsuedo is very strict for a beta, such strictness is not a welcoming for new users. But he is is fanatic about the SE policies , I guess he follows those policies more then the creators of SE themselves. Ideally he should also become a mod of CSE,JSE or hindusim.SE. He is the most unaligned person I ever came across

Comment: In short I would say , he is overqualified for a beta site.

Comment: [If a person is feeling jealous, what should they do?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23441/if-a-person-is-feeling-jealous-what-should-they-do)

Comment: Please bear in mind that you're dealing with a real person on the opposite side. We should not try to insult others by pointing their unsupported behavior. If you've to advice him something plz feel free to do it in personal chat with him with some politeness. I guess he would definitely find that beneficial. If you've issues with his moderation skills then raise a meta about those rules which are problematic to you. He doesn't rule the site, he just moderates it. It is the community which rules the community.